# Conditionally add where clause to eloquent query

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I have a products database. I allow users to enter a search term and I display products related to their search term. I'm wanting to add the ability for the user to further filter these results by "gender" using AJAX. If the user selects a gender from a select box this is sent to the URL query string.

here is my code responsible for detecting if "gender" is in the query string.

```
$searchTerm = request('s');
$gender = request('gender');

$productsQuery = DB::table('products')
                ->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%");
if ($gender != "") {
    $productsQuery->where('gender', '=', "%$gender%");
}

$productsQuery->get();
```

When this method is called. I receive an empty collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do this in one query. Just like that:

```
$productsQuery = DB::table('products')
->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
->where(function($query) use ($gender){
     if($gender != ""){
        $query->where('gender', '=', $gender);
      }
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your idea and approach is correct, but you are mixing `LIKE` and `=` queries. `%` is a wildcard, but that can be only be used with `LIKE`.

So, if you want to use a wildcard and `LIKE`,

```php
if(!empty($gender)) {
    $productsQuery->where('gender', 'LIKE', "%$gender%");
}
```

Or if you want to match by exact text,

```php
if(!empty($gender)) {
    $productsQuery->where('gender', $gender);
}
```

Your current code will search for the exact match of the literal string `%male%`, for example.

Keep in mind that by using a wildcard, `male` will also match `female` (as they both contain the word "male").

Answer (score 1):

You should use LIKE also in the second where clause:

```
$productsQuery->where('gender', 'LIKE', "%{$gender%}");
```

**EDITED**

If you need to search for the exact gender you must not use wildcards at all.

```
$productsQuery->where('gender', '=', $gender);
```

Comment: But what if the value is "male" it will match both male and female. Given that OP used `=` i dont think is supposed to be a wildcard.

Comment: It depends on what you want to search for. If you need to search for the exact word you do not use wildcards. If you need to search for the words that starts with some chars you use just 1 wildcard (the second one).

Comment: @Tolios he could also just remove the percentages and go for the `=`

Comment: Correct, but then you can drop the second parameter. It is also not what this answer suggests, and I find it hard to believe a like-operation is the end goal here